# Is there any reason to use string over String in c# (IDE0001)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded to VS 2015 and its complaining about me using the capital `String`  version of string, saying it can be simplified.

I tried googling for `IDE0001` and clicking the link but neither gave me any good info on why this is a thing. `CS0168` appears to be unrelated as well (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf85t6e4(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Is there any reason to use the lower case version over the upper case version?**

[image]

Comment: `String` is a .NET type and `string` is a C# data type.  The latter is an alias for the former.  Theoretically, that could change and it could alias a different type but that will never actually happen.  Personally, I always use C# data types in place of .NET types when they exist.  Some argue that you should use the .NET type when invoking static members and C# data types for instances.  It makes no difference to the compiled code so you should come up with a convention you're happy with and stick to it.

Comment: I basically agree with @jmcilhinney but IMO it seems silly to use one variant for one usage, and another variant for another when the two constructs are exactly identical in effect.  Does it *really* make sense to use `Int32.Parse` rather than `int.Parse`?  It seems to me that using the two different tokens for separate purposes when those two tokens are identical does nothing but sow confusion.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I can see the logic behind using .NET types for static members but I don't find it compelling enough to do so.  If nothing else, it means that you have to think about what context you're in and might then make mistakes if you don't.