# Disable IDE0001 (use string over String)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a followup question to [Is there any reason to use string over String in c# (IDE0001)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799544/is-there-any-reason-to-use-string-over-string-in-c-sharp-ide0001). I know the two types `string` and `String` are basically equal, and I personally prefer the later in many situations. Now Visual Studio 2015 always suggests to "simplify" String to string, which in my opinion is just adding noise to the code editor (the warning, not the change).

I'd like to concentrate on real warnings in code, such as unused methods or variables, which show up the same (with Resharper, at least).

Any idea how I can disable that specific warning?

Comment: Select the item giving the warning in the source code, click the lightbulb, select "Inspection" and then "Configure Inspection Severity" and turn it off?

Comment: @cremor: Thanks, that solved it.